# Most general way to make a Uri object?

Tags: .net, uri

I need to convert all of the following forms into .NET Uri object:

- "hello.world"
- "..\something\somthing"
- "../something/somthing/else"
- "c:\autoexec.bat"
- "http://whatever.com/nevermind.html"
- more or less anything else that you might expect to find in something building local or web path.

I have already checked an `new Uri("..\somthing\something")` and `new Uri("../something/somthing/else")` don't work. Also none `Uri`'s statics seem to be for this.

Any ideas beside a big logic tree and/or regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
new Uri("../whatever",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Without the RelativeOrAbsolute flag the Uri will attempt to parse a complete absolute URI.  Adding the flag will let it parse essentially any valid URI (relative or absolute)

Comment: Now why isn't that the default?! :b

Comment: @BCS, don't know.  My guess is it's following a principal of make it strict by default.